# CakePHP 2 - Issue allowing Controller's action

Tags: cakephp, permissions, cakephp-2.0

this is my situation:

I have a lang function in mi PluginAppController, where it change the locale language and it is redirected to the referer page.

I have a flag's images menu where users can do clic over them to change language too.

Then, because I have an authentication system, I want to allow users run only this action ('lang').

The problem is that my system takes the URL, but it is the referer URL, because at the end of the lang action I redirect to the referer, so I can't allow or deny this action.

My lang action code:

```
public function lang($lang = 'spa'){
  $this->Session->write('Config.language', $lang);
  $this->redirect($this->referer());
}
```

Comment: You would allow or deny in another area or with another method.  This action shouldn't be the one in control of allowing/denying access to every other action.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to allow the access to an action named "lang"?
Then put this in your beforeFilter (AppController, not your plugin's AppController)

```
$this->Auth->allow('lang')
```

Of course, this is assuming you don't have another action in your app with that name, in which case you need to check the request and determine if it is coming from your plugin

```
if ($this->request->params['plugin'] == 'yourPlugin' && $this->request->params['controller'] == 'controllerOfYourPlugin') {
   $this->Auth->allow('lang');
}
```

Comment: @GuillermoMansilla but in my AppController's beforeFilter action I call to a cuestom Component, which checks the permissions, so after '$this->Auth->allow('lang')', the URLs is forbidden, showing the next generic message: 'Yue are not autohrized to acces this location'. What I dont understand is why shows this message, because this message belongs to Auth component